# How to fix this NoReverseMatch exception in Django rest frameworks routers?

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-viewsets

I'm working on this Django project for learning and I'm not able to resolve the URL using reverse().

I have tried to understand this concept from online documentations and I'm not able to succeed with it.

I'm using `ModelViewSet` in my views.py

In my tests.py

```
POSTS_URL = reverse('posts:posts-list')
```

And this is my urls.py of posts(i.e., app)

```
app_name = 'posts'


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', PostsViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

This is my urls.py in root

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls')),
path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title='My API title')),
]
```

And this is the error I'm getting

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'posts-list' not found. 'posts-list' is not a valid view function or patternname.
```

And also can someone suggest a good place to understand properly how reverse() and routers work together..

Answer (score 1):

In your `urls.py` `app_name` doesn't seem to get used and [the router uses the model's name](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) (singular) per default, therefore `reverse("post-list")` should work.

If you want to namespace your urls you should rather do something like `path('api/posts/', include('posts.urls', 'posts'))` then `reverse('posts:post-list')` should work.

Comment: `reverse("post-list")` is also raising same exception:(