# Django REST Framework reverse() not finding match for router's "{basename}-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-viewsets

This question is **extremely** similar to: [How to fix this NoReverseMatch exception in Django rest frameworks routers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54466362/8534756) but that hasn't been answered/resolved and after a lot of investigating here I am looking for help.

I am trying to build an API with test-driven development. As common practice I begin my tests by saving constant variables for the URLS using `django.urls.reverse()`

The problem is `reverse('{app}:{basename}-list')` works fine, but `reverse('{app}:{basename}-detail')` throws the exception:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'designer-detail' with no arguments not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['api/design/designer/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/design/designer/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$']
```

My test.py: (notice the list url runs first and throws no exception)

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from designs.models import Designer
from designs.serializers import DesignerSerializer


DESIGNER_LIST_URL = reverse('designs:designer-list')
DESIGNER_DETAIL_URL = reverse('designs:designer-detail')
```

My app/urls.py:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from designs.views import DesignerViewset


app_name = 'designs'

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'designer', DesignerViewset, 'designer')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My project/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/design/', include('designs.urls'))
]
```

My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from designs.models import Designer


class DesignerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Model serializer for Designer.
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Designer
        fields = "__all__"
```

And my views.py:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from designs.models import Designer
from designs.serializers import DesignerSerializer


class DesignerViewset(ModelViewSet):
    """
    ModelViewSet for the Designer model.
    """
    queryset = Designer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DesignerSerializer
```

I have tried tinkering with the basename, the router, the app_name, the urlpatterns, but nothing seems to work. I have gone through the official docs on vanilla django and DRF. Whats **most confusing** is why `"designs:designer-list"` runs as expected but  `"designs:designer-detail"` fails? The DefaultRouter is supposed to take care of this. I manually tested this last comparison in the Django shell.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need a value for the primary key, so `reverse('designs:designer-detail', kwargs={'pk': 42})` where 42 is the primary key of the item for which you want to obtain details.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you that helped, sidenote why comment instead of answering the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this raises an error is because the URL has a `pk` parameter, and you thus need to provide a value for that in order to define the URL path.

You can pass the value of named parameters with the `kwarg=…` parameter, so:

```
reverse('designs:designer-detail', kwargs={'pk': 42})
```

where `42` is the primary key of the item for which you want to obtain details.

Comment: do you know how can I reverse NestedRouters(). I could not find answer anywhere. Also I have tried placing others nested -list in front of the nested one but with no success.